# AutoGen not found

Tags: mandriva

Anyone knows the 'AutoGen v5 not found error in Mandriva(or RPM based systems like Fedora)' for the Anjuta IDE? I checked the packages and Mandriva shows me that Autogen 5.11 is installed. Tried reinstalling both AutoGen and Anjuta and still getting the same error.

Comment: Does this work? http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=27502